# How can I use ImageMagick to batch resize and use -extent with transparency?

Tags: imagemagick, image-processing

- **Version:** ImageMagick 7.0.8-68 Q16 x64 2019-10-05
- Windows 10: 1903

I have hundreds of logos that I need to resize to a standard and then use `-extent` to pad back out.

```
magick 608000000000051.png -resize 500x325^> -gravity center -extent 500x325 done.png
```

**original** (green added to show transparency)
[image]
but it adds a white background and I want to retain the transparency. After hours of reading docs I can't find a solution, can this be done with Imagemagick?
[image]

Comment: Try using the [`-alpha`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#alpha) command line option; transparency equates too the alpha channel in ImageMagick and other image — and even video — processing tools.

Comment: I just spend 90 minutes with that command and I cannot to save my live get anything other than a white background.  TBH I'm getting quite frustrated with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! :)

This resizes your image, centers it, sets the canvas to a standard size and maintains transparency.

```
magick 608000000000051.png -background none -resize 500x325^> -gravity center -extent 500x325 done.png
```